# cffileupload not displaying anything

Tags: coldfusion

I'm having a little trouble with cffileupload.
Basically it's not displaying anything...
Either, I've missed something obvious or there's a server issue.
Here's the code (dead simple)

```
<cfoutput>
<h2>Upload new data</h2>
<p>Please choose an Excel file to upload</p>
<cffileupload url="save.cfm" / >
</cfoutput>
```

URL: http://www.office5star.co.uk/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hit that URL of yours I get a whole raft of 404s:

```
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/ext/css/ext-all.css 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/uploadfile.css 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/adapter/yui/ext-yui-adapter.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cffileupload_swf.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/ext-all.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/cf.css 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
GET http://www.office5star.co.uk/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/animation/animation-min.js 404 (Not Found) www.office5star.co.uk/:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: ColdFusion is not defined www.office5star.co.uk/:22
Uncaught ReferenceError: ColdFusion is not defined
```

And, indeed, /CFIDE is inaccessible (good).

However if you want to use this UI widgets that ColdFusion provides, you have to give it access to its resource files. If you've made /CFIDE inaccessible, you'll need to use [`<cfajaximport>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfajaximport) to avail yourself of the files from a different location.

As a rule of thumb, if something on the UI isn't working: check the browser console for HTTP and JS errors. This is the usual cause of such things.

Comment: Thanks for this - today is not a good day for my Coldfusion server - it's a managed service so I can't do too much with it.

Comment: Is there another 'widget' that I can try to implement to prove that the issue is with the server as opposed to with my code ?

Comment: How come the fact that the `<cffileupload>` can't load its necessary resources to run is not evidence in itself?

Comment: You see, I think it is but the server host company say 'everything is working fine'.
I'm really looking for some more ammunition . . .

Comment: Well: you *need* one of two things for that tags to work: a) web access to /CFIDE/scripts; or 2) the contents of that directory elsewhere that is web browseable so you can `<cfajaximport>` to reference them. If they're not providing that, they've messed up. This is fundamental CF 101 sort of knowledge (OK, maybe CF-201), and if they don't have that, I fear for the quality of your hosting. Basically you should be able to say "a bunch of stuff I need to use this CFML tag is missing from my config. Pls supply it."

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.
They 'escalated' the issue - basically first line support know little about CF. All is working correctly now with <cfajaximport>

Comment: The solution was:
The resource files '/script/' were not available so, once copied into the root folder for the site, it all sprang into life ... Just got to get it to work now :)